# How to continue test case after running a process in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I want to run a python file which starts a server (http://127.0.0.1:5000) before test case execution. Currently the process starts but execution does not go to next statement.

With **Run Process keyword** the process starts but execution does not go to next statement.

Below is the test case code with Run Process:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Process

*** Test Cases ***
SampleTestCase
    ${stat_proc}  Run Process  python  app.py
    Log  ${stat_proc}    //This statement is not executing
```

With **Start Process keyword** , it throws the below exception.
Test case code with Start Process keyword:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Process

*** Test Cases ***
SampleTestCase
    ${stat_proc}  Start Process  python  app.py
    Log  ${stat_proc}
```

**Exception with Start Process keyword**.

> ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000): Max
>   retries exceeded with url: /api/collect (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError
>   10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it'))

Can anyone help on this issue?

Comment: The [Start Process](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Start%20Process) documentation states that it should start in the background. Is there perhaps an error or infinite loop in the script?

Comment: @A. Kootstra, with Start Process connectionError exception is thrown and with Run Process process starts but execution does not go to next line.                please find the updated details in the original question posted above.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your statemen: __"The same python script works fine when executed outside robot framework."__. What is different between this and the Robot Framework context?

Comment: Outside framework when run on command line  >python app.py , server will run on console and I execute robot test case from robot framework. Now I want to automate both through robot framework 1)Running server 2) executing test case after that.
1st part I am able to achieve through Start Process i.e starting process but its not going to next line.

Comment: Does it work with any other python script than `app.py` ?